# Getting the result from the first matched condition and not consider result from the next matched condition

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement to get the result from the first matched condition and if it finds result in that level then return from there or go to Next level to 
find the result .

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you to add sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a prioritization query (with ties).  One method uses `dense_rank()`:

```
select rsc.* 
from (select rsc.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by case when rsc.entityId = :accountId and rsc.entityTypeCode = 'A' then 1
                                              when rsc.entityId = :companyId and rsc.entityTypeCode = 'C' then 2
                                              when rsc.entityId = :issuerId and rsc.entityTypeCode = 'I' then 3
                                              else 4
                                         end) as seqnum
      from CurrentRuleSetContents rsc 
      where (rsc.entityId = :accountId and rsc.entityTypeCode = 'A') or
            (rsc.entityId = :companyId and rsc.entityTypeCode = 'C') or 
            (rsc.entityId = :issuerId and rsc.entityTypeCode = 'I') or 
            (rsc.industryCode = :industryCode)
    ) rsc
where seqnum = 1;
```